# Setting an HTML object property with knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following:

```
var $video = $('<video autoplay></video>').css('max-width', '100%');
$video[0].srcObject = event.stream;
```

I'm trying to move away from jQuery manipulation and towards knockout.

Is there any way I can set an observable `activeStream(event.stream)` and have the DOM update accordingly?  Something like

```
<video data-bind="htmlProperty: {srcObject: activeStream}" autoplay></video>
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`attr`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.url = ko.observable("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<video controls data-bind="attr: { src : url }"></video>
```